# Не вызывается функция класса в main c++

Tags: c++, классы

Намучался с классом. Надо описать класс "Работник", Каждая запись содержит фамилия и инициалы, должность, год поступления на работу, зарплата. Сделать вывод всех работников, ну и поиск по определенным запросам, тип по должности и тд. Разберите пожалуйста весь код и скажите где-что, в классах много взаимосвязи, что уже путаюсь
   сам код, там помечу где ошибка:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 using namespace std;

 class Worker {
     public:
     Worker(string family="" , string inicial="" , string dolzh="" , int year=0 , double zp=0 );    
     void printListEmployees(size_t); 
     void printListEmployeesOverYear(int); 
     void printListEmployeesOverSalary(double); 
     void printListEmployeesThisPosition(string); 
     ~Worker();

     string family;
     string inicial;
     string dolzh;
     int year;
     double zp;

 };


 /*========================== KONSTRUKTOR ==========================*/

Worker::Worker(string family , string inicial , string dolzh , int year , double zp )
{
    cout<<"Введите фамилию работника  "; cin>>family;
    cout<<"Введите инициалы работника  "; cin>>inicial;
    cout<<"Введите должность работника  "; cin>>dolzh;
    cout<<"Введите год поступления на работу  "; cin>>year;
    cout<<"Введите зарплату работника  "; cin>>zp;      
}
Worker::~Worker()
{

};
/*========================== FUNCTION ==========================*/
void printListEmployees(Worker* workers, size_t count) // печать списка сотрудников
{   
    int n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<workers[i].family;
    }

    delete[] workers;
}

/*========================== MAIN ==========================*/

int  main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int n;
    cout<<"Задайте количество работников"; cin>>n;
    Worker *workers = new Worker[n];
    Worker s;
    cout<<s.printListEmployees();// вот тут не вызывается, выдает ошибку. снизу напишу.
}
```

> ошибка    In function 'int main()': [Error] no matching function for
>   call to 'Worker::printListEmployees()'    [Note] candidate is: [Note]
>   void Worker::printListEmployees(size_t) [Note] candidate expects 1
>   argument, 0 provided

Comment: вызываю тебя, @free_ze )

Comment: что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @goldstar_labs проблема решена уже, спасибо за отклик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void printListEmployees(Worker* workers, size_t count);
```

Во-первых, этот метод не является членом класса вы его определили и реализовали вне класса.
Во-вторых, сигнатура метода объявленная в классе отличается от сигнатуры вызова, сравните:

```
//Один параметр в объявлении метода
void printListEmployees(size_t);
...
//При вызове не один параметр не передается
cout<<s.printListEmployees();
```

На что компилятор и ругается.

В-третьих, сама функция `printListEmployees()` возвращает void а не строку поэтому строка `cout<<s.printListEmployees();` не корректна. Вам следует вместо этого вызвать `printListEmployees(workers, n);`

В-четвертых, у Вас внутри класса Worker объявлены следующий методы:

```
void printListEmployees(size_t); 
void printListEmployeesOverYear(int); 
void printListEmployeesOverSalary(double); 
void printListEmployeesThisPosition(string);`
```

Вы можете их удалить, так как не очень логично что какой-то один работник может выводить информацию о списке работников. Здесь вы можете объявить метод для вывода информации о работнике например:

```
string info();
```

И реализовать его так:

```
string Worker::info()
{
   // Здесь реализация....
}
```

Вы можете использовать это в функции

```
void printListEmployees(Worker* workers, size_t count) // печать списка 
сотрудников
{   
    int n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<workers[i].info();
    }

    delete[] workers;
}
```

Получается что `Worker s` Вам не нужен. Если уж хотите использовать какой-то класс для этого то создайте какой-нибудь `Company` в котором хранится список все сотрудников `Worker` и который может вывести информацию о них методом `printListWorkers()`.

UPDATE

Забыл написать про конструктор. В классе поля можете объявить через нижнее подчеркивание:

```
//...
string _family;
string _inicial;
//...
```

Сам конструктор реализовать так:

```
//Используем список инициализации
Worker::Worker(string family="" , string inicial="" , string dolzh="" , int year=0 , double zp=0) :
    _family(family),
    _inicial(inicial),
    _dolzh(dolzh),
    _year(year),
    _zp(zp)
{
   //Пустое тело
}
```

Ну в общем как-то так. В общем не опускайте руки и учитесь) Надеюсь что понятно объяснил.

Comment: а что мне даст объявление через нижнее _?

Comment: @adam_k вы можете сделать данные свойства класса приватными членами. Осуществить доступ вы можете к ним через функции так называемые геттеры и сеттеры. Вообще существуют разные соглашения по именованию приватных членов. Я например именую через нижнее подчеркивание, это поможет избежать конфликта имен, да и плюс в списке инициализации у вас не получится обратиться к `this`. Извиняюсь что не написал это в ответе.

Comment: @adam_k еще на счет списка инициализации. В нем вы можете инициализировать члены класса являющиеся константами(const, не путать с constexpr), так как в теле конструктора это сделать невозможно.

Comment: возможно ли где-то в соц сетях списаться? у меня очень напряженная ситуация с этими классами

Comment: @adam_k я думаю что вы можете писать мне на почту spoom95@gmail.com. У меня не всегда есть так много времени для того чтобы я мог оказать оперативную помощь) Напишите мне на почту, а дальше скооперируемся куда-нибудь.

Comment: пишу на почту, ожидайте

Answer (score 0):

1.Меняем

```
Worker(string family="" , string inicial="" , string dolzh="" , int year=0 , double zp=0 );

на

Worker(string family="" , string inicial="" , string dolzh="" , int year=0 , double zp=0 )
{
     this.family = family;
     this.inicial = inicial;
     this.dolzh = dolzh;
     this.year = year;
     this.zp = zp;
}
```

2.И делаем так

```
Worker s = new Worker(); // в скобочках можете параметры передать,в порядке как 
                         //указано в конструкторе
```

3. Вызываем

```
cout << s.Print() ;
```

Реализация вашей функции Print должна возвращать строковое значение

UPD: Вся подробная и понятная информация о классах в си++ здесь:

http://cppstudio.com/post/439/

Comment: дело в том, что во 2 пункте мне надо сделать динамический массив, т.е Worker *s = new Worker[n];

Comment: Тогда просто вызывайте s[i].print() элемент

Comment: не ленитесь и прочитайте статью по ссылке

Comment: хорошо, сейчас прочитаю и непонятное скажу